# Is there any other way to obtain Pumpkin seeds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On the wiki there is not reference to obtaining [Pumpkin Seeds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin_Seeds) there or on the [Pumpkin](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pumpkin) page. Can you get them without finding them in chests? If not does this mean they are not a [renewable resource](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Infinite_Blocks)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: Minecraft 1.0 has added the ability to turn Pumpkins into four Pumpkin Seeds each, by placing it into the crafting grid.

---

Currently, the only way to obtain Pumpkin Seeds is to find them in Abandoned Mine Shafts; you can't craft them like you can Melon Seeds. This means they aren't a renewable resource like Melons are. (I think this was intentional by Notch to keep Pumpkins a rare item.)

Comment: It's worth noting that due to a bug, you can't even find them in Mine Shaft chests, rendering them unobtainable.

Comment: This is no longer the case in Minecraft 1.0.0. Pumpkins may be crafted into 4 pumpkin seeds.

Comment: @KevinReid Thanks for the notification, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

In 1.9, you can just stick a pumpkin into the crafting grid and make pumpkin seeds!

Comment: There is no 1.9 - do you mean 1.0.0?

Comment: There was a 1.9 pre-release: http://youtu.be/CTZ4boILlvs

Comment: I meant from 1.9 pre-releases to 1.0.0. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: it's BETA 1.9 PreRelease... The BETA is very very important.

Answer (score 1):

Now in the more recent updates you can get pumpkins in open plains, mine shafts, villages, And many more places. But the most common are the pumpkins in the plains.

Answer (score -4):

In your world, pumpkins can spawn randomly.  So if you find those pumpkin, you can change them into pumpkin seeds in 1.5.2.